# KineticJS: Blob scaling

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I would like to ask you if it's possible to scale - Tween on height/width of a Blob object in the canvas?
Is the trick is to redefine each points according to initial position of each points?
The desired effect is to see the Blob expand/retract on itself with a certain factor value (ie. 10%).
Thank you.

Code:

```
for(var i=0 ; i<shape_childs.length ; i++){
var child = shape_childs[i]; 
var height=child.getHeight(); 
child.blobTween = new Kinetic.Tween({ 
    node: child, 
    duration: 1, 
    height:height+(height*0.20), 
    easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear 
}); 
}
```

here is a fiddle :) [jsfiddle.net/3VCKJ/1](http://jsfiddle.net/3VCKJ/1/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share the code of what you have tried until now and where you have the error/difficulty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ani says, welcome to Stackoverflow.  It's traditional to show your code so we can assist you.

The blob object, like most objects in KineticJS, can be scaled using `myShape.setScale`.

In your case, you can also set the desired scaling factor inside a tween:

```
  var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: blob, 
    duration: 1,
    scaleX: 1.1,
    scaleY: 1.1
  });
```

**[ changes given additional comments ]**

It looks like you want the blob to remain in the original x/y while scaling.

To do that, you'll want to also Tween the x/y of your blob while scaling:

```
    var tweenUp = new Kinetic.Tween({
      node: blob, 
      duration: 1,
      scaleX: 1.10,
      scaleY: 1.10,
      x:blob.getX()-(blob.getWidth()*.10),
      y:blob.getY()-(blob.getHeight()*.10)
    });
```

Unfortunately, the KineticJS blob.getWidth and blob.getHeight do not return a value (just 0).

So we need to estimate the width and height of the blob.

You can try to refine this calculation by accounting for the tension (not shown here).

```
    var blobPoints=[{x: x_r-60, y: y_r}, {x: x_r, y: y_r+35}, {x: x_r+60, y: y_r}, {x: x_r, y: y_r-55}]
    var minX=1000000;
    var minY=1000000;
    var maxX=-100;
    var maxY=-100;
    for(var i=0;i<blobPoints.length;i++){
        var pt=blobPoints[i];
        console.log(pt.x+"/"+pt.y);
        if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.x>maxX){maxX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
        if(pt.y>maxY){maxY=pt.y;}
    }
```

And then set the blob width and height properties to our calculated values:

```
    blob.setWidth(maxX-minX);
    blob.setHeight(maxY-minY);
```

Now the tween should scale the blob by 1.10 while remaining in relatively the same x/y.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XWvSP/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var sc_height = 300;
    var sc_width = 300;

    var x_r=(sc_width/2)-(40/2);
    var y_r=(sc_height/2)-(40/2);

    var blobPoints=[{x: x_r-60, y: y_r}, {x: x_r, y: y_r+35}, {x: x_r+60, y: y_r}, {x: x_r, y: y_r-55}]
    var minX=1000000;
    var minY=1000000;
    var maxX=-100;
    var maxY=-100;
    for(var i=0;i<blobPoints.length;i++){
        var pt=blobPoints[i];
        console.log(pt.x+"/"+pt.y);
        if(pt.x<minX){minX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.x>maxX){maxX=pt.x;}
        if(pt.y<minY){minY=pt.y;}
        if(pt.y>maxY){maxY=pt.y;}
    }

    var blob = new Kinetic.Blob({
      points: blobPoints,
      stroke: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 10,
      fill: '#faa',
      tension: 1.2,
      scale: 1,
      x: 20,
      y: 50
    });
    blob.setWidth(maxX-minX);
    blob.setHeight(maxY-minY);
    layer.add(blob);
    layer.draw();

    var tweenUp = new Kinetic.Tween({
      node: blob, 
      duration: 1,
      scaleX: 1.10,
      scaleY: 1.10,
      x:blob.getX()-(blob.getWidth()*.10),
      y:blob.getY()-(blob.getHeight()*.10)
    });

    $("#scaleup").click(function(){ tweenUp.play(); });
    $("#scaledown").click(function(){ tweenUp.reverse(); });

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="scaleup">Tween Scale Up</button>
    <button id="scaledown">Tween Scale Down</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you both for welcomes :)

Ok, here is the code I tried for my bloby poring :)

`for(var i=0 ; i<shape_childs.length ; i++){var child = shape_childs[i];
var height=child.getHeight();
child.blobTween = new Kinetic.Tween({
node: child, 
duration: 1,
height:height+(height*0.20),
easing: Kinetic.Easings.Linear
});   
}`

Comment: But I'm wondering if scale is the proper property to use for what I'm trying to do.
I would like to "zoom" on each shapes that compose my drawing, I mean to modify height and width of each shapes by 10% for example.

Comment: You'll want to also Tween the x/y of your blob while scaling.  See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer. I understand well now how we can manage special objects just like Blob, Spline, etc.
Thank you :)